# How to read the cookies from the jsp application using classic asp page

Tags: jsp, cookies, asp-classic

I am working with the classic asp, here I have to call the jsp application(A small window, which will store some values in the browser cookies on a button click). So i need to get the values from the browser and has to display in a browser as well as need to store it in database.

So please give some same works how to get the cookies value from that jsp applicaton to my classic asp application.

In jsp they are storing the cookies value using key value pair.

Please help me on this.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? What isn't working?

Comment: Have you tried looking at `Request.Cookies`?

Comment: I haven't tried anything Bret, But thise same progress has been done by someone in another module. so copied and used to our requirement! and its working.. But why iam posted here is to know the logic and ideas of you all.

Comment: So post the code/logic, and ask the questions you have about it.